# How do I make Synaptics touchpad feel more like on Windows?

Tags: touchpad, 19.10, synaptics

In Win10 the touchpad feels good with stock/OEM Synaptic drivers, it's very accurate/slow when I move my finger slowly on the pad and when I move my finger fast the speed of the cursor is much faster / more accelerated and I can cover the whole screen.

On Ubuntu 19.10 I can either the speed to so slow that I can't cover the whole screen or if I make it faster it's so inaccurate that it's hard to press small buttons or do other precise things.

How can I make the touchpad feel more like it does in Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Kubuntu 18.04 LTS user here.  I've had similar problems. I expect what follows will apply to regular Ubuntu also.

Out of the box Ubuntu uses libinput for its touchpad control.  libinput only has one setting for the pointer speed: the acceleration setting. The older Synaptics driver has minimum speed, maximum speed and acceleration.

I'm using a Huawei Matebook X Pro and found libinput's default pointer speed on the touchpad to be very slow.  I had to increase the acceleration to speed up normal movement but then any quick movement was over-accelerated.

**WARNING! This can disable all input:** Installing package `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-18.04` installs the Synaptics driver and it automatically overrides the libinput driver.  I have seen a problem where some Ubuntu updates can break libinput so both the touchpad and the keyboard stop working.  (Perhaps there's a better way to install or configure the Synaptics that avoids this problem.)

If you install Synaptics this way I strongly recommend you have a way to rollback.  I use [Timeshift](https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift). After a bad update I booted from a Live Linux USB and used Timeshift to rollback, then reboot, uninstall `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-18.04`, install OS updates and finally re-install `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-18.04`.

*Extra info*

Low-level touchpad settings can be seen by running `xinput list` to find the ID of your touchpad, then run `xinput list-props <device ID>`. Change a setting with `xinput set-prop <device ID> <property ID> <value>`.

The Synaptics driver also has "coasting"/"kinetic scroll" [which libinput will never support](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/faqs.html#kinetic-scrolling-does-not-work).

Comment: Do you know how I can check wether or not it switched from libinput to synaptics? And if it worked, how can I configure it to feel good?

Comment: In Kubuntu the System Settings Touchpad page has a lot of greyed out options with libinput. When Synaptics is installed settings become usable, including the minimum and maximum speed which are on the same tab as the acceleration. I assume there are similar settings in Ubuntu.

Also, when I run `xinput list-props <device ID>` I have an entry like this:
`Synaptics Move Speed (323):     1.853379, 5.545244, 0.108566, 0.000000`
I think the first three values are min speed, max speed and acceleration.  I don't know what the `0.000000` is.